# Disable CSS for a HTML Microsite

Tags: html, css

I have a website with some CSS. On this site is an affiliate microsite.
The problem is, my CSS affects the microsite and I cant change the microsites elements.

I'm looking for a solution to disable my CSS only for this microsite.
(The microsite is just a JS file who print out the HTML).

```
<img src="image" align="bottom" width="1" height="1" border="0" hspace="1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="microsite.js"></script>
```

Comment: Some code please. How do you implement the Microsite?

Comment: <img src=\"http://image" align=\"bottom\" width=\"1\" height=\"1\" border=\"0\" hspace=\"1\"><script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://microsite.js\"></script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is open the said micro site in invisible iframe.

Comment: In my opinion this is the only way that this is possible. Its ugly, cause, iFrame. Still, correct answer!

Comment: This is a possibility but i dont like iframes. Isnt there a way to overwrite my css for the microsite? I just need to change the the high and font size tag.

Comment: It should be, but will only work in html 5 scope. Read this article for a howto. http://css-tricks.com/saving-the-day-with-scoped-css/

Comment: Thanks guys, it workes good with the style scoped. I like this more than a iframe.

Comment: @user3688653 Beware that scoped css is not supported in IE, Opera or Safari https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @user3688653 Then it would probably work the same without the `scoped` attribute ;)

Answer (score 1):

As a answer to future visitors,

In the comment's there's said that style scoped works. 
http://www.css-tricks.com/saving-the-day-with-scoped-css

The question was indeed solved with this answer.

But, as another commenter said, it doesn't work in Opera, IE and Safari. (Also see, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style#Browser_compatibility)